# Get Route from Controller and method

Tags: playframework-1.x

In Play if I want to get the string form of the route how do I get that from the controller and method declaration?

eg

```
Application.home()
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/routes#reverse

```
String url = Router.reverse("Application.home").url;
```